# Cordova app restarts when launched from homescreen

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I am building an Android app using Apache cordova (through the Chrome Mobile Apps framework). Let's say I want to launch the app, and it has been previously started. There are two ways I can do this:

1. Go the the home screen launcher and click the application icon.
2. Use the Android multitasking button (recent apps button) and click on
   the application that way.

When I do #1, the app fully restarts and I get the Cordova `deviceready` event, but when I do #2 I get the Cordova `resume` event and the app resumes from where I left off without having to completely reload.

How can I always get behavior #2, or get it as often as possible? I don't know why the app would behave differently depending on how I re-enter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Chrome Apps for Mobile are you using?  We patched cordova-android to change the default `android:launchMode` which changed to fix the behaviour exactly as you describe.

I don't recall the exact version that landed, but likely somewhere around a month ago.  Please upgrade cca (with `npm install -g cca`), *then also upgrade your application*, which should be much easier now that the latest version thanks to the new `cca upgrade` command.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution (based on what you said and what I've read).  I was on cca `0.1.0` and now I am on `0.1.1`.
  Interestingly enough, I switched my homescreen launcher on Android and the problem went away without even needing to upgrade cca.  With the 'Google Now' launcher that I had sideloaded (apk from Nexus 5) it had the problem, but with my standard Motorola Launcher (Droid Maxx) it does not.

Comment: Whoa, thats interesting.  We'll make sure to keep an eye out for that one.

Comment: @hatboysam If you can reproduce that issue with latest cca with consistency on the custom launcher, please file a bug with repro steps over on our github issue tracker please!

Comment: it seems to be fixed in cca `0.1.1`, strange that there was definitely a difference between launchers in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
```

Also note that be careful to use deviceready in index.html

Comment: KeepRunning is slightly different -- its more of a battery setting.  Given the behaviour described that the effect is different when running from icon/switcher, I'm pretty sure the actually setting to check is `AndroidLaunchMode`, and the default has changed recently.

Comment: @mmocny Well, thanks for your comment. I will look into your description later.